# How to use Windows 7 Soft AP in 802.11n mode?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a [TP-Link TL-WN727N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=243&model=TL-WN727N) which I use to create an access point for my Android phone to connect to.

In Device Manager, I can enable "Adhoc support 802.11n" and it'll work in 802.11n, however Android phones have a hard time connecting to them.

Creating a soft AP either from command line (`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ...`) or with Connectify will work, and the phone can connect to it, however it is only 802.11b with a max speed of 54 Mbps.

The output of `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` is:

```
Hosted network settings
-----------------------
    Mode                   : Allowed
    SSID name              : "Police Surveillance Van"
    Max number of clients  : 20
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP

Hosted network status
---------------------
    Status                 : Started
    BSSID                  : f4:ec:38:98:83:60
    Radio type             : 802.11b
    Channel                : 1
    Number of clients      : 1
        cc:f9:e8:86:ec:c4        Authenticated
```

I didn't find any way to change radio type or the channel. Googling around revealed some other dumps, which had 802.11n as the radio type, so it's possible somehow.

The XML file exported by `netsh wlan export hostednetworkprofile` supports setting the radio type, since it has a `<phyType>` tag, [according to its docummentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706965.aspx). However, this is not set on the file exported for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the protocol for most wireless adapters by bringing up the device manager, opening the properties for the wireless adapter and selecting the "Advanced" tab. The "Wireless Mode" setting on the left lets you choose between b/g/n.

Comment: A hostednetwork shows up under the device manager as "Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport Adapter" and does not have an Advanced tab.